# Can't add views or inflate within View Pager inside an Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-cardview

I used an external library called "Swipe Cards by Diolor" and I attached it to an `Array Adapter`. Within each card I also need to make a `View Pager` with bars showing which image the user is currently looking at. The issue I am having is that when I set an `OnPageChangeListener`on the View Pager it calls method`onPageSelected` and executed all the code within it. This involves a call to `createBars` (included below). However, everything in `createBars` is executed including the `barHolder.removeAllView` except for the `li.inflate` statements. I also tried using `addView` but a similar problem occurs. Please advise a method to work around this and if possible the resoan why it's happening. I have included code from the `Array Adapter` code for the `createBars` and `getView` methods. Let me know if some other piece of code would be helpful.

```
 private void createBars(int position, int numItems, LinearLayout barHolder) {

    barHolder.removeAllViews();
    Log.i("View pager listner", "method called");


    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        if (i == position) {
            li.inflate(R.layout.white_rectangle, barHolder);
        } else {
            li.inflate(R.layout.transparent_white_rectangle, barHolder);
        }
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // all views required for a card
    final ProgressBar homeProgressBar;
    final TextView homeTimeLeft;
    TextView homeTitle;
    CardView homeItemHolder;

    HomeItem item = getItem(position);
    final int numItems = item.getItemImages().length;

    if (itemView == null) {
        itemView = li.inflate(R.layout.home_item, parent, false);
    }


    homeProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_progressbar);
    homeTimeLeft = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_time_text);
    homeTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_card_title);
    homeViewPager = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_view_pager);

    homeViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);

    timeLeftItem = item.getTimeLeftMiliseconds();
    homeTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

    HomeImageHolder viewPagerAdapter = new HomeImageHolder(context, item.getItemImages());
    homeViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    final LinearLayout barHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_bars);
    createBars(0, item.getItemImages().length, barHolder);

    homeViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.i("view pager listner", "it listned");
            createBars(position, numItems, barHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftItem, milisecondsInHours) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            homeTimeLeft.setText(HelperMethods.milisecondsToDays(millisUntilFinished) + " Days "
                    + HelperMethods.milisecondsToHours(millisUntilFinished) + " Hours");
            homeProgressBar.setProgress(updateProgressBar(millisUntilFinished));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            homeTimeLeft.setText("0 Days 0 Hours");
            homeProgressBar.setProgress(updateProgressBar(0));

        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();

    return itemView;
}
```

The inflator works when it's called outside the listener but not when it is called inside it. What would be the reasoning being this?

EDIT: I figured out that the class to which the array adapter is added, (Diolor's swipe cards) calls getView 4 times on the future objects in the array. Could this be a potential issue. I know that the reference to bar holder within the listener does not change for a given card. I used Logs and toString methods to confirm that the LinearLayout passed into the listner coincided with the barHolder that corresponds to the current card.

Comment: after inflate are you adding view to **barHolder**

Comment: please refer this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging--mobile-8231)

Comment: Hey, I saw your link. However that link doesn't explain my question - its about how a view pager works. And the default parameter to inflate is true, so yes the views are being added to barHolder